# Getting 2d array key values in Javascript or PHP?

Tags: php, javascript

I have a table of in which all the cells have a textbox to edit cell data.  Now I want to use ajax to save data to a table for each keyup event.  I have each textbox named as a 2d array that contains 2 ids, 1 id for each key, that I want save in a table.

```
<input type="text" name="txtfield[1][2]" />
```

now those 1 and 2 keys are ids that I want to save each in a separate column in a table.

Is there an easy way of getting those key values or should I use some string manipulation to get those values?

Any suggestions either in javascript or php would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would probably be easier to name them

```
<input type="text" name="txtfield-1-2" />
```

Then, in PHP, you access them with

```
for (i = 1; i <= m; i++)
    for (j = 1; j <= n; j++)
        whatever($_POST["txtfield-$i-$j"]); /* or $_GET[...] */
```

In JavaScript, you do something like

```
for (i = 1; i <= m; i++)
    for (j = 1; j <= n; j++)
        whatever(document.getElementById("txtfield-" + i + "-" + $j).value);
```

I am assuming that these are in some kind of grid, so `m` and `n` are known. If not, Ek0nomik's solution would suit you better, although the regex should be `\.*\[([0-9]+)\]\[([0-9]+)\]` (`\[` and `\]` should go outside of `(...)` and quantifier `+` should be added to allow indexes larger than 9) or, a bit more precise, `^txtfield\[([0-9]+)\]\[([0-9]+)\]$`.

Answer (score 0):

You can get those values in both Javascript or PHP.  Just use a regular expression:

An example (this could be made more specific if needed):

```
/.*(\[[0-9]\])(\[[0-9]\])/
```

PHP Example:

```
preg_match_all('/.*(\[[0-9]\])(\[[0-9]\])/', 'txtfield[1][2]', $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
//Do something with $matches.
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd prefer using jQuery, separating the data from the name value and avoiding regex.

```
<input type="text" data-apples="some_value" data-oranges="some_value" id="yourID" />
```

In jQuery:

```
var apples = $('#yourID').data('apples');
```

to retrieve the values needed.